# Code is wrong or? in C

Tags: c

I wrote this code:

```
float suma;
int centy;
int cele;
printf("Zadaj sumu a ja ti ju napisem a zaroven aj vysklonujem:\n");
scanf("%f",&suma);
cele=(int)suma;
centy= (suma-cele)*100;

switch ((int)suma) {
    case 1:
        printf("%d euro",(int)suma);
        break;
    case 2 ... 4:
        printf("%d eura",(int)suma);
        break;

    default:
        printf("%d eur",(int)suma);
        break;

}
switch (centy) {
    case 1:
        printf(" a %d cent\n",centy);
        break;
    case 2 ... 4:
        printf(" a %d centy\n",centy);
        break;

    default:
        printf(" a %d centov\n",centy);
        break;
}
```

But when I type 5.56 it will say that I have typed 5.55 in console. What do you think. What should I change? I am newbie so...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3185968

Comment: Everything is right except your expectation :)

Comment: You expect `suma-cele` to be 0.56, but it might be 0.5599999999999999.

Comment: Ehm, since when is `2 ... 4` valid. What did I miss?

Comment: @BoPersson It's float. Not nearly that many nines.

Comment: The actual value is 0.559999942779541015625. So multiply by 100 and round, e.g.  `centy = round( (suma-cele) * 100.0 );`

Comment: Most important fact when dealing with currencies: **Do not use floating point**.

Comment: @Olaf That's a fine point of view, and I don't disagree with you. I suggest that you post an answer that shows how to input a fixed point number, because that's the part that's difficult for a beginner.

Comment: @user3386109: Noo time/too lazy. Feel free. But there are already dozens  of Q/A here about this subject. They pop up regularily like new "security" laws.

Comment: @Olaf My point was that you shouldn't be downvoting bruceg's perfectly valid answer, unless you're willing to take the time to provide a better answer.

Comment: I think 2 ... 4 is a non-standard gcc extension

Comment: @user3386109: Nice idea to require providing a better answer if you DV. However, afaik there is no such rule, yet. And the answer does not cover the actual problem, but provides a temporal workaround (without mentioning it is a workaround) which will eventually create larger problems (if not for this project, but for a potential latter - give a fish vs. teach how to fish). Finally: It would have been better to comment at the answer then.

Comment: @bruceg: You are right. It is an extension.

Comment: Ah, [Case Ranges - Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to correct for rounding errors when using floating point numbers.  An easy way that often works is to add 0.5 before converting to an int.  So, something like this should work better:

```
centy= (int) (0.5 + suma * 100.0) - cele * 100;
```

It's probably better to read the input as a string and parse it into euros and cents using the '.' as a delimiter. But this will get the code working easily. Adding 0.5 often works when you don't need exact precision, but close enough will do.

Comment: Thanks man. It works

Comment: No. When dealing with currencies or other precise values, never use floating point. Use fixed-point integers instead (e.g. calculate in cents or a fraction thereof).

Comment: I agree.  It's probably better to read the input as a string and parse it into euros and cents using the '.' as a delimiter, but I wanted to get his code working easily.  Adding 0.5 often works when you don't need exact precision, but close enough will do.

Comment: Please add that comment to the answer. I'll remove the DV then.

Comment: There, I think that's an answer we can all live with, thanks @Olaf.

Comment: Still not happy with it, but removed the DV. Hope my comment above will help. And the question might be closed soon anyway as a dup.